# Should I leave the company that I have been with for 20 years because they will not hire more help?

Tags: job-change, quitting, stress, resignation

I am a Network Manager and have been with the same company from 20 years.  I have always liked working hard(maybe too hard) and taking on any responsibility they could throw at me.  Six months ago I had a heart attack and when I got back to work I asked management for another person to back me up.  I hoped this would help my stress level and maybe help the company if I had more health issues.

Management's first response was "Yes, we have known for years that you needed more help".  At first that did not bother me because they said yes, but after five months of waiting they finally told me that I need to wait at least seven more months(if they can find the funds).

Now I am mad because of their first response, they new I needed more help!  I have applied for another job and it looks like a great fit with a team instead of just me.  But I feel sad about leaving since I have been here for so long it is like a home and family to me.

Am I off base by thinking this way?  How long should one wait before making a change or is it too late?

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/441/should-i-quit

Comment: They don't care about your health, they don't care about the health of their system (or it woudl not be inteh sole hands of someone who just had a heart attack) or they would make this a priority. I would not feel in the slightest bit guilty for moving on. likely you will be able to swing a large pay raise as well.

Answer (score 5):

**Your health is key**

In life your work should NOT be any where near your highest priority. Personal Health, family, financial well being, etc all should come ahead of work.

**Time for change**

Heart attacks don't just happen. It's a slow road of too much stress, poor exercise, and/or poor eating. (each of these increase risk, the more of those boxes you can check the higher the risk)

Now it's up to you to make whatever changes are needed to reduce your risk. Work is one of our primary sources for stress, and if you can't change the situation at your company you need to change your company.

**New digs vs Old**

Okay, so you've got a new opportunity on a team lined up. First does it seem like it will truly be less stressful, or are you hoping stress will be diluted a bit as there are more people there to split it between? (Since lowering stress is the factor here, it's also our main consideration)

If it seems indeed less stressful, you need to decide what would be necessary for your employer to retain you. (if you want to consider retention) It sounds like you do.

I'd be direct, put in your notice and explain you just can't risk compromising your health further. If they ask what they can do to make you reconsider then make your terms clear. (And don't budge, this isn't chatting about a raise, this is chatting about your physical well being, don't settle for anything less)

They'll either meet / exceed your request or not. If your happy with their response you might have a future together, if not move on. There are very few jobs in this world worth dying for.